# Spring @RequestMapping with optional parameters

Tags: java, spring, rest, api, spring-boot

I have problem in my controller with optional params in requestmapping, look on my controller below:

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Books>> getBooks() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(booksService.getBooks());
}

@GetMapping(
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
    params = {"from", "to"}
)
public ResponseEntity<List<Books>>getBooksByFromToDate(
    @RequestParam(value = "from", required = false) String fromDate,
    @RequestParam(value = "to", required = false) String toDate) 
{
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(bookService.getBooksByFromToDate(fromDate, toDate));
}
```

Now, when I send request like:

```
/getBooks?from=123&to=123
```

it's ok, request goes to "getBooksByFromToDate" method
but when I use send something like:

```
/getBooks?from=123
```

or

```
/getBooks?to=123
```

it goes to "getAlerts" method

Is it possible to make optional params = {"from", "to"} in @RequestMapping ? Any hints?

Comment: Hi, I'm also looking for same, if you got a solution, please update

Answer (score 10):

Use the default values. Example:-

```
@GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<List<Books>> getBooksByFromToDate(@RequestParam(value = "from", required = false, defaultValue="01/03/2018") String fromDate, @RequestParam(value = "to", required = false, defaultValue="21/03/2018") String toDate) { 
.... 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `defaultValue` as explained in [the Spring's docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html#defaultValue--):

> #### defaultValue
>
> The default value to use as a fallback when the request parameter is
> not provided or has an empty value.