# Spring @RequestMapping with optional parameters when using custom request object

Tags: java, spring, controller

Hello I want to make an optional parameter on my controller, `id` that so far looks like this

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "get runs by date in order to paginate")
    @ApiResponses({ @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unexpected failure") })
    @RequestMapping(value = "/time/{date}/to/{toPage}/from/{fromPage}",
                    params = {"pageSize", "id"},
                    method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RunCollection getPolicyByDate(GetPolicyByDateRequest request) {
        return serviceImpl.getListOfRunsByDate(request);
    }
```

But this means the parameter is required. I want it to be optional. I saw this answer where they use `@RequestParam` [Spring @RequestMapping with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49403150/spring-requestmapping-with-optional-parameters) but I want to include it in my `GetPolicyByDateRequest` object. Is this possible? The spring docs don't allude to turning off the required attribute. Could I possibly use `Optional`

Comment: "I want to include it in my `GetPolicyByDateRequest` object" GET requests do not have any body. I'm not sure how are you planning on getting `GetPolicyByDateRequest` method parameter from a GET request?

Comment: Since this is under the hood I wasn't sure how it worked @narendra-choudhary. Does the request object not hold all the request data? Because it picks up all 4 other parameters just fine as long as the name is the same

Comment: Have a look at [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-requestmapping#2-multiple-pathvariable) for using `@PathVariable`.

Comment: I know I can do it with `@RequestParam` but I want to keep it in my `Request` object. That is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options :

1. If your `GetPolicyByDateRequest` has not **primitive attribute**, they should be inserted by Spring in your object. If your parameter is not set (i.e there is no `pageSize` in your url) then Spring injects NULL in your attribute.

```
public class GetPolicyByDateRequest {

    private String date;
    private int toPage;
    private int fromPage;
    private Integer pageSize;
    private Integer id;

    public GetPolicyByDateRequest() {
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getToPage() {
        return toPage;
    }

    public void setToPage(int toPage) {
        this.toPage = toPage;
    }

    public int getFromPage() {
        return fromPage;
    }

    public void setFromPage(int fromPage) {
        this.fromPage = fromPage;
    }

    public Integer getPageSize() {
        return pageSize;
    }

    public void setPageSize(Integer pageSize) {
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyRequest{" +
                "date='" + date + '\'' +
                ", toPage=" + toPage +
                ", fromPage=" + fromPage +
                ", pageSize=" + pageSize +
                ", id=" + id +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Weirdly, I think it is some king of bug in Spring, even when using `Optional` you get a null object if the parameter in the requestParam is not provided.

2. If you want to get all parameters, you need to use `@PathVariable` with `@RequestParam` in your case. Here is how to get your parameters :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/time/{date}/to/{toPage}/from/{fromPage}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public RunCollection getPolicyByDate(@PathVariable String date, @PathVariable int toPage, @PathVariable int fromPage, @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<Integer> pageSize, @RequestParam(required = false) Optional<Integer> id) {
        // then use your parameters the way you to use then.
    }
```

Please note :

- `@PathVariable` retrieves the parameter in the URL, where the value is between `{}`, like `{date}` -> `@PathVariable String date`
- `@RequestParam` retrieves the parameter after the `?` in the URL. `?pageSize=10` -> `@RequestParam int pageSize`.
- Both of this annotation takes as parameters, among others, `required=true|false`. When do mark a parameter as not required, make sure you don't use a primitive type, like int, otherwise, you can set null to this object, and your code will fail at runtime. This is the reason why I have used `Optional<Integer>`, to allow the type. But Spring is clever, and if it detects the `Optional` in your parameter, then you are forced to use `required=false` in the `@RequestParam`.

If you wanted to populate your `GetPolicyByDateRequest`, then you should have done a `POST` mapping, and use the annotation `@RequestBody GetPolicyByDateRequest request`, and send a JSON body in your request to make Spring (actually Jackson) translate your JSON into a `GetPolicyByDateRequest` object.

Hope it helps

Comment: your first option is the setup I have but spring complains if the parameters are not there. I'm looking for a way to keep it in the request object without needing it to be mandatory

Comment: What is your spring version ? Because It is working well for me

Comment: looks like 4.2.1

I get this error when passing one and not the other param

```There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Parameter conditions "pageSize, id" not met for actual request parameters: pageSize={25}```

Comment: looking at this link, it does not seem possible on any version https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param

Comment: remove the `params = {"pageSize", "id"},` attribute and give it a try.

Comment: but I need the `params` to identify them as part of the query string instead of the path

Comment: Like I've said, Spring is clever. `@RequestMapping(value = "/time/{date}/to/{toPage}/from/{fromPage}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getPolicyByDate(GetPolicyByDateRequest object) {` is my working code. Spring will do many things for you, including setting the param in the URL (at least for me)

Comment: yup you are correct. I missed that our signature's were different. The `optional` bug is annoying, but it's the solution I will go with.